# hidden table in Xcode

Tags: xcode, uiview, storyboard

![enter image description here][1]I've seen this feature in a few apps.  The Facebook app for example has a button that when pressed the main view slides to the right and a secondary view is displayed.  The second view has a list of items which the user can click on.  What is this called.  I thought it was just a scrollview on top of a view but when I run my app the second view isn't displayed.

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PartsViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIScrollView *mainScroll;
}
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[mainScroll setScrollEnabled:YES];

[mainScroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 500)];
}
```

Like I stated this didn't show the second view.  Not sure if I need a swipe gesture.  I believe I need an action an a button.

Ok so here is how I managed to create my sliding menu.
[image: First view]
[image: my slide menu]

.h
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController  {

```
IBOutlet UIButton *main;
IBOutlet UIButton *parts;
IBOutlet UIButton *project;
IBOutlet UIButton *misc;
IBOutlet UIButton *close;

IBOutlet UIScrollView *ButtonScrollView;   
}


- (IBAction)showButtonScroll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hideButtonScroll:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Button Scroll View
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(767, 75,391 , 940);

}

- (IBAction)showButtonScroll:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(377, 75, 391, 940);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction)hideButtonScroll:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(767, 75, 391, 940);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

With it being a scroll view I can add whatever items I want and place it where ever I want to.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work around.  There are images at the top of this string to show what my menu looks like.

```
.h @interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIButton *main;
IBOutlet UIButton *parts;
IBOutlet UIButton *project;
IBOutlet UIButton *misc;
IBOutlet UIButton *close;

IBOutlet UIScrollView *ButtonScrollView;   
}


- (IBAction)showButtonScroll:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)hideButtonScroll:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Button Scroll View
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(767, 75,391 , 940);

}

- (IBAction)showButtonScroll:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(377, 75, 391, 940);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

- (IBAction)hideButtonScroll:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
ButtonScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(767, 75, 391, 940);
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```